# Are TLS connections in china mostly encrypted with AES or with SM4?

Tags: tls

What is the dominant symmetric cipher used for TLS connections in China? Is it AES, as it is in the US, or is it SM4?

Answer (score 2):

I think as of June 2020, it's still AES, as SM4 isn't <s>registered in IANA</s> formally backed by an RFC yet, and most browsers used by netizens in China are based on Chromium (some users use FireFox, and some government websites still requires IE!).